# How to kill quartz scheduled threads?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, quartz-scheduler

I had added quartz scheduler code earlier in our application and now I have removed that code.

The job was scheduled to run every hour.

But now I have removed that code and deployed new war which does not have that code.

But now also I can see logs like below every one hour,

10:00:00.001 [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_Worker-4]

How to kill these threads?

Comment: Have you tried to restart `Tomcat`?

Comment: Yes I have restarted tomcat. But it did not help.

Comment: What is `webapps` folder content?

Comment: 2 war files.  One is java rest api application war and the other is front end web project war

Comment: maybe you have used db to store the jobs and the quartz tables are still there?

Comment: No. No table are created for this

Comment: Thank all. The issue is resolved. there were 2 instances of tomcat were running.

Answer (score 0):

If you are making use of quartz jdbcstore, you need to delete the trigger and job detail records from database.